# Youtube Embed breaks on mobile Safari

Tags: css, iframe, safari, transform

I am encountering a weird issue once again, and it again happens to be in Safari on iPhone. Safari on macOS works fine, and so do all other major browsers.

Here's the issue: Embedding a YouTube video in an `iframe` transforms the `iframe` to the left, out of the viewport. **There is no transform applied to the `iframe`, or any parent elements.** I double checked, but I am out of luck. Funnily enough, there's two quirks:

1. The clickable area stays non-transformed. I can interact with the content as if it was in its correct position.
2. Switching to the tab overview renders the video correctly.

Here's a few screenshots to demonstrate the issue:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have also [created a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vq1rsybo/) that reproduces the issue, with markup directly out of the project. Visit it on mobile Safari on iPhone or with a simulator on macOS to see the problem in action. (Use [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/vq1rsybo/embedded/result) for fullscreen access)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you find a solution?

Comment: is this are you looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/yt0wo21r/3/